# How to transpose row data into column data by adding two rows data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data like this as shown below

```
Name    Price
Steve   10
Arnold  15
Arnold  20
Joseph  30
Steve   25
```

My requirement is to bring the output as shown in the image below.

```
Sum(Arnold)        sum(steve + joseph)
35                 65
```

Please suggest some code for this.

Comment: Can you give more details about the rules to a more generic solution and also what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You'll use a CASE statement inside of a SUM()

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Name]='Arnold' THEN [Price] ELSE 0 END) as [Sum(Arnold)],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Name] in ('Steve','Joseph') THEN [Price] ELSE 0 END) as [Sum(Steve + Joseph)]
FROM yourtable
```